# Controls event not executing after calling webmethod using jQuery Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, vb.net

I am using cascading dropdownlist in my gridview edit template. For binding dropdownlist I used some class which is called using a web method, up to this all works fine, it is binding dropdown very well.

Now problem is I wrote some code under second dropdownlist selected indexchanged event but it wont execute the selected index changed event of second dropdown. I set autopostback=true and EnableEventValidation="false", but no luck.

How can I execute the second dropdown selected index changed event? Also it is not executing any other control's event which is in the gridview edit template.

Note: I used all dropdownlist in gridview EditTemplate.

VS 2010,code-behind:Vb.net

Here is my code:

```
//calling webmethod using JqueryAjax
var $ddl = $("select[name$=cbCompany]");
      $ddl.select2();
      var $ddlSub = $("select[name$=cbCategoryName]");

      loadSubjects($("select option:selected").val());
      $ddlSub.fadeIn("slow");

      $ddlSub.bind("change keyup", function () {

          $ddlSub.select2();

          loadSubcategroy($ddlSub.val());

          $cbSubCategoryName.fadeIn("slow");
      });
  }

  function loadSubjects(selectedItem) {

      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "frmTimeBilling.aspx/GetSubjectList",
          data: "{deptAliasName:'" + selectedItem + "'}",
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          dataType: "json",
          async: true,
          success: function (data) {
              printSub(data.d);

          },
          error: function (xhr, status, err) {
              var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
              alert(err.Message);
          }
      });
  }

  function printSub(data) {
      $("select[name*=cbCategoryName] > option").remove();
      $("select[name*=cbCategoryName]").append(
                $("<option></option>").val("Select Subject").html("Select Subject")
                );
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          $("select[name*=cbCategoryName]").append(
                    $("<option>  
    </option>").val(data[i].subAliasName).html(data[i].subName)
                );
      }
      $("#subjectdiv").css("display", "block");
      $("select[name$=cbCategoryName]").select2();
  }
```

Below is the web method code which is call using above jQuery Ajax method

```
<WebMethod()> _
<ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet:=False, ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json)> _
    Public Shared Function GetSubjectList(ByVal deptAliasName As String) As List(Of   

Data)
        Dim [sub] As New Data()

        Dim lstSubs As List(Of Data) = [sub].GetCategory("", "CategoryName",   

deptAliasName).ToList()
        Dim a As Integer = lstSubs.Count


        Return lstSubs
    End Function
```

This is event which is not executed after binding dropdownlist using jQuery ajax method.

```
 Protected Sub cbCategoryName_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

 tbName.text="Your Selected category is blah blah"

 End Sub
```

I made some changes (I used loadSubcategroy($("select option:selected").val()); instead of loadSubcategroy($ddlSub.val());) in above code then it hit the selectedindex_changed event. But now problem after postback, it lost all the data which is bound using jQuery.

So how I can save the data in dropdownlist after postback?

Comment: Does `cbCategoryName` have any items in the list which are bound from your code-behind?  If not, `cbCategoryName_SelectedIndexChanged` is not going to trigger because it doesn't know the index changed.

Comment: @onskee : yes  cbCategoryName dropdownlist get binded using webmethod 
which is calling from client side jquery ajax.So in cbcategoryName Dropdown list there is a all most 20-25 items.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, my response still stands.  Because you're filling the dropdown list client-side, the ViewState does not contain any items, thus it won't work the way you're doing it.  You're mixing two different platforms (jQuery and .NET).

Option 1 - Wrap your dropdowns in an `UpdatePanel`, and handle the databinding from the code-behind.  This will put the ListItems in ViewState which will allow your submit button's event to see the values.

Option 2. - Do everything with jQuery.  Your submit button can get to the value of your dropdown by using `Request.Form(cbCategoryName.UniqueID)`.  The downside to this method is that the dropdown lists will not retain their listitems on postback.

Comment: I did edit my post yesterday to reflect changed code.

For Option 1:I already used update panel and I wrapped my gridview in the update panel.If I bind dropdown from code-behind I am not able to use nearest matching functionality which implemented in jquery.

Option2:I have to execute the code-behind selected_index changed event because I need to hide or display some column s of the gridview, code for the same is there. Right now I able to execute selected_index changed event but I lost my binded data after postback.

Do you want to go through Markup code ?